# Using Redux Saga in a big project

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am new to reactjs and trying to learn saga.

I have built a root saga file as follows.

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { watchBookFetchRequest } from './bookSaga'
import { watchAuthRequest, watchIsLoggedInRequest, watchLogoutRequest } from './authSaga'

export default function* rootSaga() {
   yield all([
    watchAuthRequest(),
    watchBookFetchRequest(),
    watchIsLoggedInRequest(),
    watchLogoutRequest()
   ]);
}
```

For each module, i have created a separate saga file and put all those related actions in that file.

Finally, i took all those actions and combined them in root saga.

> I assume, when the project becomes big and more complex and has a lot
>   of modules, all the watchers will be added in the same way like the
>   above code

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
   yield all([
    watchRequest1(),
    watchRequest2()
    .
    .
    .
    watchRequestn()
   ]);
}
```

That is, the root saga will be containing quite a lot of watchers - Watchers for login, dashboard, books, accounts and so on..

**Is this the correct way of doing this?**

Comment: We just export arrays with the sagas from each module, and then spread them into the array passed to `all` in the `rootSaga`

Answer (score 6):

Organising sagas is a lot like organising reducers. You will also probably start up using combineReducers in root reducer with a flat list of all reducers and it can even scale pretty well. Long lists of reducers/sagas aren't usually a source of much problems.

However eventually in both cases you might want to introduce a tree structure. For example if your application looks like this:

```
+-- services/
|   +-- live-updates/
|   |   +-- live-updates-saga.js
|   +-- local-storage/
|   |   +-- local-storage-saga.js
|   +-- services-saga.js
+-- sections/
|   +-- home/
|   |   +-- home-saga.js
|   +-- contacts/
|   |   +-- contacts-saga.js
|   +-- sections-saga.js
+-- root-saga.js
```

You might run your sagas this way:

```
// root-saga.js
function* rootSaga () {
    yield all([
        fork(servicesSaga),
        fork(sectionsSaga),
    ])
}

// services-saga.js
function* servicesSaga () {
    yield all([
        fork(liveUpdatesSaga),
        fork(localStorageSaga),
    ])
}

// sections-saga.js
function* sectionsSaga () {
    yield all([
        fork(homeSaga),
        fork(conactsSaga),
    ])
}

// live-updates/local-storage/local-storage-saga.js
function* liveUpdatesSaga () {
    yield takeEvery(XYZ, xyzSaga)
}
```

I wouldn't call either solution the "correct" one. Just experiment what suites you better.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Martin...

> I wouldn't call either solution the "correct" one. Just experiment what suites you better.

He's right but you want to hear from other devs so: in my current project the file system is organised as Martin showed but the root saga is still elementary

```
export function* rootSaga() {
  yield spawn(authSaga);

  while (true) {
    yield take(LOGIN_SUCCESS);
    // the indipendent sagas are all started after the LOGIN_SUCCESS action

    const tasks = [
      yield fork(pollBtcValueSaga),
      yield fork(getConfigSaga),
      yield fork(setTimeSaga),
      // and so on...
    ];
    console.log("sagas started");

    yield take([LOGOUT_REQUEST, FREEZE]);

    // the indipendent sagas are all stopped after the LOGOUT_REQUEST (or FREEZE) action
    for (let i = 0, n = tasks.length; i < n; i++) {
      yield cancel(tasks[i]);
    }
    console.log("️sagas stopped");
  }
}
```

In my root saga the only difference is that I spawn the authentication saga. That makes the auth saga completely independent (like if I would have started with `sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);`).

Then all the other sagas are started after a `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action and canceled after a `LOGOUT_REQUEST` one.

I then introduced the `FREEZE` action just for debugging purposes (I have a lot of network polls and logging that can bore me while debugging).

Anyway as the project grows I'll introduce the organization proposed by Martin.

Answer (score 0):

I use InitSagas and call it after initializing the Redux Store

```
//initSagas.js

import * as sagas from './sagas';

  const initSagas = (sagaMiddleware) => {
    Object.values(sagas).forEach(sagaMiddleware.run.bind(sagaMiddleware));
  };

export default initSagas;
```

I have a `index.js` in my Sagas folder and export all sagas from it to consume in InitSagas.js

In my `getStore.js`

```
//getSore.js
...

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(...enhancers));

initSagas(sagaMiddleware);

return store;
```

Hope this answers your question.